# Php : Laravel - Array push after using eloquent pluck method

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, array-push

here is my Query

```
$RecipientList = Employees::select(DB::Raw('CONCAT(first_name," ",last_name) as employee_name'),'email')->pluck('employee_name','email');
```

which give me the proper result as i want,

but after i execute query i have 1 more key => value pair to push in the result array.

If i print the current result , its something like this .

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection Object
(
    [items:protected] => Array
        (
            [punit@*****.com] => Punit Gajjar
            [milan@*****.com] => Milan Gajjar
            [pritesh@*****.com] => Pritesh Modi
            [pratik@*****.com] => Pratik Modi
            [jyoti@*****.com] => Jyotiranjan J..
        )

)
```

Bit if i try to push my Key=>valye pair into this array it dosn't work.

```
array_push(array("All"=>"All"),$RecipientList);
```

Need Output something like

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection Object
    (
        [items:protected] => Array
            (
                [All] => All
                [milan@*****.com] => Milan Gajjar
                [milan@*****.com] => Milan Gajjar
                [pritesh@*****.com] => Pritesh Modi
                [pratik@*****.com] => Pratik Modi
                [jyoti@*****.com] => Jyotiranjan J..
            )

    )
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is because $RecipientList is Collection and not the Array.

Try this

```
RecipientList = Employees::select(DB::Raw('CONCAT(first_name," ",last_name) as employee_name'),'email')->pluck('employee_name','email')->toArray();
```

If this does not work, try below code

```
RecipientList = Employees::select(DB::Raw('CONCAT(first_name," ",last_name) as employee_name'),'email')->get()->pluck('employee_name','email')->toArray();
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 4):

You have `Illuminate\Support\Collection` object not array. You can do

```
$RecipientList->push(["All"=>"All"]);
```

UPD: There is `prepend`method

```
$RecipientList->prepend('All', 'All');
```

Comment: Nope..  My result is  `Illuminate\Support\Collection Object
(
    [items:protected] => Array
        (
            [punit@*****.com] => Punit Gajjar
            [milan@*****.com] => Milan Gajjar
            [pritesh@*****.com] => Pritesh Modi
            [pratik@*****.com] => Pratik Modi
            [jyoti@*****.com] => Jyotiranjan J..
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [All] => All
                )

        )

)`  after using your solution.

Comment: @PunitGajjar How about `prepend` method? `$RecipientList->prepend('All', 'All');`